# Loop over spreadsheet rows to convert pdf to text using filenames in spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, loops, pdf

I have modified the code below to loop so that it can convert multiple PDFs to text files.  The PDF filenames are in spreadsheet column A and the text-file filenames are in spreadsheet column C.  However, the looping code seems to be incorrect, as I can only get the first file to be converted and it gets stuck randomly.  Not sure if any kind souls can give some advice? thanks!

```
Sub ConvertPDF()

Dim sfile As String, dfile As String
Dim AcroXApp As Acrobat.acroApp, AcroXAVDoc As Acrobat.AcroAVDoc
Dim AcroXPDDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc, jsObj As Object, Row As Long

Row = 2

sfile = Sheet1.Range("A" & Row).Value
dfile = Sheet1.Range("C" & Row).Value

Do While ws("Sheet1").Range("A" & "row") <> ""
Set AcroXApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set AcroXAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
AcroXAVDoc.Open sfile, "Acrobat"
Set AcroXPDDoc = AcroXAVDoc.GetPDDoc
Set jsObj = AcroXPDDoc.GetJSObject
jsObj.SaveAs dfile, "com.adobe.acrobat.plain-text"

AcroXAVDoc.Close False
AcroXApp.Hide
AcroXApp.Exit
Loop
Row = Row + 1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Row = Row + 1` assignment should be before the `Loop` statement, not after it.  Otherwise, `Row` never changes, giving you the behaviour you mentioned.

Similarly, `sfile =...` and `dfile = ...` should be after the `Do`, not before it.  You want all the per-file code between the `Do` and the `Loop`.

Here's the edited version:

```
Option Explicit   ' At the top of the file - always use it

Sub ConvertPDF()

    Dim sfile As String, dfile As String
    Dim AcroXApp As Acrobat.acroApp, AcroXAVDoc As Acrobat.AcroAVDoc
    Dim AcroXPDDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc, jsObj As Object, row As Long

    Dim row As Long       ' *** Added - required by Option Explicit

    row = 2

    Do While ws("Sheet1").Range("A" & CStr(row)) <> ""     ' *** Moved up; use CStr

        ' *** Now you are in the body of the loop, so do everything that relates to this row.

        sfile = Sheet1.Range("A" & CStr(row)).Value
        dfile = Sheet1.Range("C" & CStr(row)).Value

        Set AcroXApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
        Set AcroXAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
        AcroXAVDoc.Open sfile, "Acrobat"
        Set AcroXPDDoc = AcroXAVDoc.GetPDDoc
        Set jsObj = AcroXPDDoc.GetJSObject
        jsObj.SaveAs dfile, "com.adobe.acrobat.plain-text"

        AcroXAVDoc.Close False
        AcroXApp.Hide
        AcroXApp.Exit

        ' *** End of the code for this row

        row = row + 1    ' *** Go on to the next row - moved before the Loop
    Loop
End Sub
```

`CStr(foo)` expressly converts `foo` to a String.  I added it above for clarity.

You could further speed up your code by using `Cells` instead of `Range`, if you wanted to.

Comment: @chanhongchon Glad to hear it!  And THANK YOU for helping push me over the line to 10k reputation!  :D :D